# How to speed up a query with few intersect operations

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there a way to speed up a query with few intersect operations? Query looks something like this:

```
SELECT TOP(2000) vk_key FROM ( 
SELECT vk_key FROM mat_property_det where [type]='mp' AND (ISNULL(mat_property_det.value_max, ISNULL(mat_property_det.value_min, 9999))  <=  980 OR ISNULL(mat_property_det.value, 9999) <= 980) AND mat_property_det.property_id=6 
INTERSECT
SELECT vk_key FROM search_advance_mat WHERE 1=1 AND (search_advance_mat.group_id = 101 ) 
INTERSECT
SELECT vk_key FROM  V_search_advance_subgroup_en WHERE CONTAINS((Subgroup_desc, Comment, [Application], HeatTreatment), ' "plates*"') ) T
```

We don't know in advance how many intersections will we have and we couldn't change intersection with e.g. inner join because query is created from application according to user's search parameters.
Here is an execution plan:
[image: ExecutionPlanImage]

Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Comment: ISNULL(mat_property_det.value, 9999) <= 980)  same as mat_property_det.value <= 980

Comment: Have you tried breaking the query into pieces, i found that storing parts of large queries into smaller tables and using them to further refine your results is much faster than a single larger query, Dare i say an Access style approach is usually the more effective approach although it requires a little more logic and imagination.

Answer (score 0):

Help/Advice:  Focus on the Table Spool (Lazy Spool) in your execution plan, as it is consuming 36% of the query effort.  You should be able to mouse hover over that area of the plan and discover the table/view/function/etc involved.

As MSDN states for lazy spools, [the spool operator gets a row from its input operator and stores it in the spool, rather than consuming all rows at once](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191221(v=sql.105).aspx), which means every row is being scanned, one at a time.

Do everything you can to remove the Table Spool and/or improve the performance in this specific area of the query/execution plan and the entire query will benefit.